# Mongoose query with two arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

> What is the query that returns the values in 'all' array,  excluded
> the values in 'friends' array

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  all: [],
  friends:[],
 .... 
});

all = [ObjectId('65ss135442890aa'), ObjectId('65ss135442890dd')];

friends =[ObjectId('65ss135442890aa')];
```

> result of query should be <ObjectId('65ss135442890dd')>

Comment: does [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P-QEjh9xs8k) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `$setDifference`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      all: {$setDifference: ["$all", "$friends"]},
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BgDGgh5jIqC)